# How to display percentage label on top of each bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am novice to R.I am using ggplot to display bar plot.I want to display percentage of top of every bar.I don't want to convert y-axis to percentage label.Rather i want to display frequency in y-axis and percentage of every group on top of bar.

My data Snippet is

[image]

And my desired output snippet is

[image]

Any helps are welcomed

Comment: Use `geom_text` to do this, and please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of plot can be created easily with `ggplot2`.

```
dat <- data.frame(Frequency = c(10, 5, 97, 47, 50),
                  Fruits = gl(5, 1, labels = c("Mango", "Apple", "Orange", 
                                               "Guava", "Papaya")))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Fruits, y = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f%%", Frequency/sum(Frequency) * 100)), 
            vjust = -.5)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Sven .I had not worked in ggplot.After Using this package i figured out it was easy too.

Comment: @Sven Is it possible to add one more plot with same levels but different color and percentage like amount of target in that variable?